# org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load core configuration for core collection1

Tags: solr

I am trying to reproduce an Solr issue, But unfortunately with the provided schema & solrconfi, Solr is throwing exception.

Here is the files -

Full stacktrace :- http://pastebin.com/nmj9h2BX

Schema file :- http://pastebin.com/iwMpr7a5

Solrconfig file :- http://pastebin.com/UadPu5GV

I tried to remove the data-config handler, as I have nothing to do with this, I got an another exception.

Stack trace - http://pastebin.com/zXyZhMnN

Any clues Please, Thanks!

Comment: Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: No system property or default value specified for dataimport.config value:${dataimport.config}

Comment: @sidgate yeah I removed the dataimport config handler from solrconfig, Still getting an another exception.

Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "text_general": Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/filter: Error instantiating class: 'org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.StopFilterFactory'. Schema file is /home/hackers/trunk/solr/example/solr/collection1/schema.xml

Comment: Looks like stopwords.txt file is missing. How have you deployed this server? looks like you are missing most of the files/env variables. First go through SOLR documentation to understand schema.xml.

Comment: stopword file is already is my conf directory, which environment variables you meant to say ?
I am using jetty to deploy to server.

Comment: Have you checked all of the stop words file specified in schema.xml? Like lang/stopwords_bg.txt?  If you can, please try to remove these unused stopwords filters.

Comment: And if you do not use/have these files(extracted from your schema.xml), you might want to get them or comment out. https://gist.github.com/leoh/9813795

Comment: @leoh okay, let me comment that out, good catch !

Answer (score 4):

The problem you have with DataImportHandler is because you are referencing a variable `${dataimport.config}` that doesn't exists neither a default value to it. To solve this you can create this variable in your `core.properties` file with a valid DataImportHandler xml config file or just define a default value to it like that: `${dataimport.config:data-config.xml}`. Note that the data-config.xml must exists and be a valid configuration file. If you doesn't need DataImportHandler you can just remove the handler.
The second problem you have is that you are setting the parameter `enablePositionIncrements=true` in `StopFilterFactory` that doesn't exists anymore since solr 4.4. You just need to change the filter like that:

```
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
```

Note that the file `stopwords.txt` must exists.